# D3 Update bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I'm relatively new to D3, but I have been trouble shooting this issue for a few days, with no luck. Wondering if I'm making a newbie mistake.

I'm attempting to create a graph which represents volume vs. time, and allow the user to update the graph with a different date range.

```
function updateVolumeGraph(data, div) {

//Get the data again
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.startTime = new Date(d.startTime);
    d.totalVolume = d.totalVolume;
});

//Scale the range of the data again 
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.startTime;}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.totalVolume; })]);

//Select the section we want to apply our changes to
var graphElement = d3.select(div).transition();

var bars = graphElement.selectAll(".bar").data(data); <<< Undefined

//Add some bars
bars.enter().append("rect")
             .attr("class", "bar")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.startTime); })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.totalVolume); })
              .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.totalVolume); })
              .attr("width", barWidth);

    svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
        .duration(750)
        .call(xAxisVolume);
    svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
        .duration(750)
        .call(yAxisVolume);
};
```

My issue comes at the place where I have tagged it as "Undefined". graphElement.selectAll(".bars") returns an array of "rects" but the .data(data) call is undefined.

Any advice you could offer would be most appreciated!

Comment: `graphElement` is a selection returned from a call to `.transition()`. I'm not sure that a "transitioned" selection can do `.data()` binding. Try changing it to `var graphElement = d3.select(div)` (i.e. no `.transition()`) and see if that changes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are setting `graphElement` to the return value of you call to the `transition` method.

```
var graphElement = d3.select(div).transition();

var bars = graphElement.selectAll(".bar").data(data);
```

Instead of chaining these methods, try calling it as a separate call after setting the `graphElement` variable.

```
var graphElement = d3.select(div);
graphElement.transition();
var bars = graphElement.selectAll(".bar").data(data);
```